# Converting double precision IEEE 754 hex to base 10 with repeating decimals

Tags: arithmetic, computer-science, number-systems, floating-point

The number is `0x4001 8CCC CCCC CCCC`.

So far I have the stored exponent as `1000000000` which equals `2^10` or `1024`.
Stored exponent subtracted by bias number is `2^1`.

I have the mantissa as `1.0001 1000 1100 .... 1100`.

My problem is when I try to compute the `1100` repeating part. How do I represent this?

I know I have to input the remianing repeating decimal part into `x` so I can get the correct base 10 value using this forumla: `(1 + (1/16 + 1/32 + x) * 2^1`.

Comment: $( 1 + 1/16 + 8/16^2 + 12/16^3 ( 1 + 1/16 + 1/16^2 + \cdots + 1/16^{10}) ) \times 2^1$

Comment: @achillehui Is there a more compact way to represent this so that I can enter it into a calculator?

Comment: The repeating part form a geometric progression. We have $$1 + 1/16 + 1/16^2 + \cdots + 1/16^n = \frac{1 - 1/16^{n+1}}{1 - 1/16}$$.

Comment: @achillehui Plugging in to [WolframAlpha](http://tinyurl.com/lhcprpr) I get the wrong value. The answer is supposed to be `2.19374999`. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: The correct expression one should use is `2*(1 + 1/16 + 1/32 + 12/(16)^3*(1-(1/16)^11)/(1-1/16))`. Plug this into [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*%281+%2B+1%2F16+%2B+1%2F32+%2B+12%2F%2816%29^3*%281-%281%2F16%29^11%29%2F%281-1%2F16%29%29) will give you `2.1937499999999996447...`. In the repeating part, each term is $1/16$ smaller than the previous term, not $12/16$.

Comment: @achillehui I see now, thanks. If you would like, post this in the answers and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary64 format of IEEE754 [double precision number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) using 64 bits to represent a
floating point number. This representation consists of three pieces:

- sign bit: 1 bit
- exponent: width 11 bits (exponent offset 1023).
- significand: precision 53 bits (52 explicitly stored).

If you are given a number $X$ with hexadecimal/binary pattern

$$
\require{enclose}
\def\xD{{}_{10}}
\def\xH{{}_{16}}
\def\xB{{}_{2}}
\newcommand{\xP}[2][black]{\color{#1}{\enclose{box}{\small\verb/#2/}}}
\begin{align}
  &\xP{4001 8CCC CCCC CCCC}\xH\\
= &\xP{0 - 100 0000 0000 - 0001 0100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100}\xB
\end{align}$$

The sign bit is stored as $\xP{0}\xB = 0$. This means $X$ is positive.

The exponent is stored with binary pattern $\xP{100 0000 0000}\xB = 1024$.
Since the exponent offset is $1023$, the actual exponent for $X$ is $1024 - 1023 = 1$.

The significand is stored with hexadecimal pattern $\xP{1 8CCC CCCC CCCC}\xH$.
Together with the implicit leading $1$-bit, this corresponds to the number

$$1 + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{8}{16^2} + \frac{12}{16^3} + \frac{12}{16^4} + \ldots + \frac{12}{16^{13}}$$

Combine these 3 pieces, the number $X$ is

$$\begin{align}
& (+1) \times 2^{1} \times \left[ 1 + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{8}{16^2} + \frac{12}{16^3}\left(1 + \cdots + \frac{1}{16^{10}}\right)\right]\\
= &
2 \left[1 + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{8}{16^2} + \frac{12}{16^3}\left(\frac{1-16^{-11}}{1 - 16^{-1}}\right)\right]\\
= & \frac{1234971460318003}{562949953421312}\\
\approx & 2.1937499999999996447286321199499070644378662109375\ldots
\end{align}
$$